# MySQL Appending to Log File from Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, logging, logfile

I've done a lot of googling, and read a lot of different stack exchange posts. I'm trying to do some logging in stored procedures.

I've looked at but have not had full success with:

1. [mysql stored procedure with INTO OUTFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265517/mysql-stored-procedure-with-into-outfile)
2. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27553/mysqldump-error-cant-create-write-to-file
3. [MySQL how do you append to a file with INTO OUTFILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721175/mysql-how-do-you-append-to-a-file-with-into-outfile)

I found that by altering my.cnf with the `[mysqldump]` section, then I was able to write to the file once with the `INTO OUTFILE` command. When I try to run it again, it complains because the file already exists. I've also tried the TEE command, but get an 'Unsupported statement' when I try to run it. It looks like this command was introduced in MySQL 4.x and I'm using MySQL 5.x.

My end goal is to be able to write to a file, which can be used like a trace file, by logging information, if certain conditions are found. I really don't care how it is done, as long as I can do it. Any ideas on how to accomplish this, or what I'm doing wrong with the TEE command?

Comment: Instead of doing the output to a file, I think I'm going to create a db table with a text field and write the data there. I think the file stuff isn't working as a security precaution.

Comment: what you are saying in comments is what I would do

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table, enter the needed data in each phase, and select everything before removing it. something like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MY_PROC;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC()
BEGIN
   DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE l_user_id INT DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users INTO n;
   SET i=0;
   CREATE temporary TABLE if not exists tmplog (i_value varchar(20), user_id varchar(20)) engine = memory;

   WHILE i<n DO
      SELECT user_id INTO l_user_id FROM users LIMIT i,1;
      INSERT INTO tmplog VALUES(i, l_user_id );
      SET i = i + 1;
   END WHILE;
   SELECT * FROM tmplog;
   DROP TABLE tmplog;
End;
;;
DELIMITER ;
CALL MY_PROC();
```